# Implementing Google Enhanced e-commerce Tracking with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

## Implementation of Google e-commerce in my code

I already have implemented the `dataLayer` variables and events in my code thanks to [Google Tag Manager e-commerce implementation guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce).

Thus, I do have in my code some portion of javascript like this:

```
<script>
/**
 * Call this function when a user clicks on a product link. This function uses the event
 * callback datalayer variable to handle navigation after the ecommerce data has been sent
 * to Google Analytics.
 * @param {Object} productObj An object representing a product.
 */
function(productObj) {
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'productClick',
    'ecommerce': {
      'click': {
        'actionField': {'list': 'Search Results'},      // Optional list property.
        'products': [{
          'name': productObj.name,                      // Name or ID is required.
          'id': productObj.id,
          'price': productObj.price,
          'brand': productObj.brand,
          'category': productObj.cat,
          'variant': productObj.variant,
          'position': productObj.position
         }]
       }
     },
     'eventCallback': function() {
       document.location = productObj.url
     }
  });
}
</script>
```

## Implementation in Google Tag Manager

According to [Google Analytics e-commerce guide](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en), I should simply add a tag in Google Tag Manager this way:

In Tag Manager, create a Universal Analytics tag with these additional settings:

- Set the **Track Type** to either **Page View** or **Event**.
- In the Google Analytics Settings variable, under **More Settings > Ecommerce**, set **Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features** to *True*.
- Select **Use Data Layer**.

Yet, the **More Settings > Ecommerce** does not exist...

[image]

So, how am I supposed to implement Google Enhanced Ecommerce using Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Ecommerce requires the Track Type - Transaction tag, Enhanced Ecommerce requires a Track type of Pageview or Event.

To access the More Settings option, click the checkbox for *Enable overriding settings in this tag* directly below the option Google Analytics Settings. It will then reveal the other settings you are after 
[image]